# Passing a variable from a public class to a public static class

Tags: c#

I have a `public` class and need to use one of those variables inside a `public static` class. Is this possible? If so: how can I call it?

```
public class xmlData
{
    public string testing;
}

public static class fileUpload
{
    public static string uploadFile(string file)
    // I want to use the testing here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would inject an instance of the `xmlData` into the method. Like this:

```
public static string uploadFile(xmlData data, string file)
```

Now inside that method you can do this:

```
data.testing ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To access instance field from static method is not possible. You can pass value as parameter:

```
public static string uploadFile(string file, string testing)
```

Or pass object into method:

```
public static string uploadFile(string file, xmlData data)
{ string testing = data.testing;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

of course it's possible.  you just pass it in.

```
string myString = fileUpload.uploadFile(testing);
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the methods I can think of in one single spot:

```
public class xmlData
{
    public string testing;

    // part of "first option"
    public void RunStatic() {
        fileUpload.uploadFile(testing);
    }
}

public static class fileUpload
{
    // used by "option 1, 3"
    public static string uploadFile(string testing) {
        var firstOption = testing;
    }

    // used by "option 2"
    public static string uploadFile(xmlData myObject, string file) {
        var secondOption = myObject.testing;
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var objectExample = new xmlData();

        // first example
        objectExample.RunStatic();

        // second example
        fileUpload.uploadFile(objectExample, "");

        // third example
        fileUpload.uploadFile(objectExample.testing);
    }
}
```

All of these will work and should hopefully answer the question. A different question might be whether or not its a good idea to expose instance variables directly or should a property be used. Hm.